# What is the metro broadcast in the Paris metro for a suspicious package?

Tags: trains, france, paris, ratp

I was in the Paris metro and the train got stopped due to a suspicious package. I didn't understand the broadcast message because it was in French. I only became aware of this after everyone went out and some other passenger told me what happened. Now I am really curious what the broadcast message is for such situations (so I can listen to it repeatedly and recognize it next time).

Comment: Was it a pre-recorded message or was it a live announcement?

Comment: There would probably have been a combination of “colis”, “bagage” or “sac” and “suspect” or “abandonné”.

Comment: Usually it is never pre-recorded because the traffic impact can be a lot different depending on the case

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Is this a travel question or a question about the French language?

Comment: @gerrit I heard both recorded and live announcements. There were (maybe) 6 broadcasts across 3 stations before everyone cleared out.

Comment: I once was in CDG airport in Paris when a bomb threat came through and they had to evacuate the terminal. Despite CDG being the 10th largest airport in the world, every announcement was in French only. NOT A SINGLE ANNOUNCEMENT WAS IN ENGLISH. As a result pandemonium ensued since almost know one knew what to do,  where to go or what was happening in the first place. It took forever to get everyone out and back in again. Fortunately there was no actual bomb, otherwise the carnage would have terrible.

Comment: @Hilmar It's not like the UK is any better...

Comment: @Leaderboard: how so? The de-facto common language of international travel is English. The norm is that all announcements at an international airport will be in English and the local language(s) (and maybe the languages of the airline and destination for a specific flight). I would assume announcements in the UK would be in English which meets expectations since it just happens to be both the local language and the international travel language

Comment: @Hilmar fun fact: the last bomb threat in Europe that turned out to be true was ~30 years ago in Ireland during "The Troubles". Every bomb threat since has always been fake, though bombings without a prior threat did happen since.

Comment: Not true, @JonathanReez, a few years ago there were a series of bombs in several European airports. The reaction was to check everyone trying to enter the airports, with long queues outside the buildings.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, unfortunately there were actual *bombings* but not credible bomb *threats*. Real terrorists are not interested in warning anyone.

Comment: @JonathanReez the [2006 Madrid-Barajas bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_Madrid%E2%80%93Barajas_Airport_bombing) comes to mind as a counterexample, as that came with an hour's notice during which an evacuation took place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key word is 'colis suspect' (which is the translation of your question), but as stated by Frank, it would rarely be announced by the driver, but instead will be written on the station's screens, and sometime announced on station speakers (which 9 times out of 10, you won't be able to hear/understand while in the train, even as a native French).

Other keywords:
Incident/accident voyageur (they are calling an ambulance).
Accident **grave** voyageur (they won't bother with ambulance).

Comment: (+1) It seems the actual phrase used by the RATP is “accident grave de voyageur“. I looked it up because I initially didn't believe it for several reasons (“accident grave voyageur“ is not grammatical in French, the SNCF uses the phrase “accident de personne”, which is not limited to passengers) but it turns you were right that they do use something very close to that.

Comment: I also learned that, like “accident de personne”, “accident grave de voyageur“ is about a collision with the train or a limb stuck in the doors. Apparently, they also use “malaise important” if someone dies on a train for another reason.

Answer (score 3):

If the announcement was only made in French, it means it was made by the metro driver. They have the discretion on the exact phrasing of the announcement, so we can’t guess it. Your best bet is to follow the crowd or use some live translation app (but that’ll likely have issues handling the announcement audio quality).

Answer (score 2):

The term is "colis suspect" (koh-lee sus-pay) or "colis abandonné", (koh-lee aban-donnay). However, you should be aware that this sort of announcement has somewhat become of a meme in France, in the sense that the situation will never be handled by authorities or anyone else in a way that makes sense if the package had a reasonable chance of being an actual bomb. There even was an incident earlier this year with [a passenger opening the "colis" themselves](https://www.sudouest.fr/redaction/insolite/le-passager-d-un-tgv-ouvre-lui-meme-un-colis-suspect-pour-que-le-train-ne-parte-pas-en-retard-14071945.php) because they knew it would make the train late for no reason.

Statistically, you ought to be far more worried about crossing the street in Paris than of any terrorist act. If you don't experience anxiety over crossing the street, then you shouldn't with this either.